Linux Audio - How to identify the audio input device index to use for audio recording
How to identify the Linux audio input device index to use for recording? Sound Settings shows as the input device.

However, the code (bottom) shows four sof-hda-dsp. When using 0, it does not record. When using 4, it does record. Why 0 does not work and how to identify which index to use?
----------------------record device list---------------------
Input Device id  0  -  sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,0)
Input Device id  4  -  sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,6)
Input Device id  5  -  sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,7)
Input Device id  6  -  sysdefault
Input Device id  7  -  samplerate
Input Device id  8  -  speexrate
Input Device id  9  -  jack
Input Device id  10  -  pipewire
Input Device id  11  -  pulse
Input Device id  12  -  upmix
Input Device id  13  -  vdownmix
Input Device id  14  -  default

lshw does not give a clue about audio input device index.
...
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=64
             resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f irq:220 memory:62892a0000-62892a3fff memory:6289000000-62890fffff

...
  *-input:10
       product: sof-hda-dsp Headphone Mic
       physical id: e
       logical name: input24
       logical name: /dev/input/event18
  *-input:11
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
       physical id: f
       logical name: input25
       logical name: /dev/input/event19
  *-input:12
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
       physical id: 10
       logical name: input26
       logical name: /dev/input/event20
  *-input:13
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
       physical id: 11
       logical name: input27
       logical name: /dev/input/event21

speech_recognition shows the similar but I am not sure how to identify which is the input device index to use.
import speech_recognition as sr
for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for microphone(device_index{0})".format(index, name))
-----
   0 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,0), ALSA (2 in, 0 out)
   1 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,3), ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   2 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,4), ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   3 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,5), ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
   4 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,6), ALSA (2 in, 0 out)
   5 sof-hda-dsp: - (hw:0,7), ALSA (2 in, 0 out)
   6 sysdefault, ALSA (128 in, 0 out)
   7 samplerate, ALSA (128 in, 0 out)
   8 speexrate, ALSA (128 in, 0 out)
   9 jack, ALSA (2 in, 2 out)
  10 pipewire, ALSA (64 in, 64 out)
  11 pulse, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
  12 upmix, ALSA (8 in, 0 out)
  13 vdownmix, ALSA (6 in, 0 out)
* 14 default, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
  15 SOUNDPEATS TrueAir2, JACK Audio Connection Kit (2 in, 1 out)
  16 sof-hda-dsp Headset Mono Microphone + Headphones Stereo Microphone, JACK Audio Connection Kit (0 in, 0 out)
  17 sof-hda-dsp Digital Microphone, JACK Audio Connection Kit (2 in, 0 out)
  18 sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones, JACK Audio Connection Kit (0 in, 0 out)
  19 sof-hda-dsp HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output, JACK Audio Connection Kit (2 in, 2 out)
  20 sof-hda-dsp HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output, JACK Audio Connection Kit (2 in, 2 out)
  21 sof-hda-dsp HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output, JACK Audio Connection Kit (2 in, 2 out)
  22 GNOME Settings, JACK Audio Connection Kit (6 in, 6 out)

Code
import pyaudio
import wave
from IPython.display import (
    Audio, 
    display
)
import librosa


FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
# RATE = 44100
RATE = 48000
CHUNK = 512
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "recordedFile.wav"
device_index = 2
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

print("----------------------record device list---------------------")
info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

print("-------------------------------------------------------------")

index = int(input())
print("recording via index "+str(index))

stream = audio.open(
    format=FORMAT, 
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE, 
    input=True,
    input_device_index = index,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)
print ("recording started")
Recordframes = []
 
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    Recordframes.append(data)

print ("recording stopped")
 
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
 
waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(Recordframes))
waveFile.close()

Environment
VERSION="22.04 LTS"
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"

$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 6: DMIC (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 7: DMIC16kHz (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

